# How to alter/remove this inline javascript with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I found this script in the head of a website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

function Ext_Detect_NotInstalled(ExtName,ExtID) {
}

function Ext_Detect_Installed(ExtName,ExtID) {
    alert("We have found unwanted extension. Please contact support")
    window.location = "logout.php"
}

var Ext_Detect = function(ExtName,ExtID) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.onload = function(){Ext_Detect_Installed(ExtName,ExtID);};
    s.onerror = function(){Ext_Detect_NotInstalled(ExtName,ExtID);};
    s.src = 'chrome-extension://' + ExtID + '/captured.js';
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}

var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

function displayErrorAndLogout() {
    alert("Please use chrome browser to view the content");
    window.location = "logout.php"
}

if (is_chrome==true)
{
    window.onload = function() { Ext_Detect('Chrome','ngpampappnmepgilojfohadhhmbhlaek');};
} else {
    is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('crios') > -1;
    if (is_chrome == false){

        if (detectIE()){
            displayErrorAndLogout()
        }

        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('UCBrowser') > -1) {
            displayErrorAndLogout()
        }
```

This script check internet download manager extension and popup a logout message.
Is this possible to remove or alter this inline java script using Greasemonkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the check for the Chrome addon, it's easy: the script assigns a function to `onload`, so if you simply assign something else to `onload`, `Ext_Detect` will never run, and your extension will not be detected:

```
window.onload = () => null;
```

Unfortunately, the other part that checks for `crios` and `UCBrowser` and runs `detectIE` runs *synchronously*, presumably at the beginning of page load, and userscripts cannot reliably run at the very beginning of page load, so that behavior may not be possible to alter, though you could try it with `@run-at   document-start`: `displayErrorAndLogout` calls `alert` before assigning to `window.location`, so if you make it so that `alert` throws an error, the location will not change:

```
@run-at    document-start
// ==/UserScript==
window.alert = function() {
  throw new Error();
};
```

Comment: Im a newbie :( can you please provide me a tempermonkey script ? It will be your great help :)

Comment: I did - a script with the code in the first code block is all you need to keep the `onload` handler from running, you just need that one line of Javascript.

Comment: Not working, still prompts that logout error and change the location :(

Comment: Under which conditions? Is the onload handler running, or is it entering the `else` block? I tried it on my own site, and the onload handler gets properly reassigned, and like I said, `@run-at document-start` isn't reliable enough (it may only work when there's a synchronous blocking script to load in the `<head>`, or something like that).

Comment: If you're on Tampermonkey, you can try to enable instant script injection (Settings => Experimental) in conjunction with `@run-at document-start`, but that's not guaranteed to run ASAP either, unfortunately. (`document-start` *will* work on Firefox-Greasemonkey, though)